# Why can't I upload GRBL but I can upload other sketches

Tags: usb, uploading

I had GRBL running on an Arduino UNO (China Copy).

When I tried to update to the newest GRBL Version I was not able to upload the sketch:

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding)

I was unable to reprogram a bootloader via another ARDUINO (Arduino ISP) but I was able to update the firmware (dfu-programmer)

The funny thing is that I was only able to program the DFU as AT90USB82 not as ATmega8U2 while the chip has an ATmega8U2 printing.

I can upload any example sketch from Arduino IDE but not GRBL.

Any suggestions?